# How to set python homebrew version as default in macos Catalina

Tags: python, homebrew, macos-catalina

For quite some time now I have been having problems configuring python and as a result I have many versions installed. When I enter the command `which -a python python2 python2.7 python3 python3.6 python3.7 python3.8` I get the following:

```
/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python2
/usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/local/bin/python3
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3.7
```

But searching by hand I also found:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python
/usr/local/Cellar/python@2
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8
```

`which python` shows that the default python is pointing to systems python, not homebrew

```
/usr/bin/python
```

My `.bash_profile` config is:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/opt/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

I want to achieve a few things:

1. Control python from Homebrew only.
2. Maintain the factory python installations in MACOS Catalina and
   remove those that are not needed.
3. Set homebrew's python as my default installation.

Edit 1:
After following all the instruction given by @Akbar30bill I have the following error:

```
Stevens-MacBook-Pro:~ setegonz$ python ––version 

/Users/setegonz/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/bin/python: can't open file '––version': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

i highly suggest using [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) its brew compatible and managing python version is easy to install just use

```sh
$ brew update
$ brew install pyenv
```

Add pyenv init to your shell

```sh
$ echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Restart your shell

```sh
$ exec "$SHELL"
```

Install Python versions into $(pyenv root)/versions

```sh
$ pyenv install 3.8.1
$ pyenv global 3.8.1
```

it also manages pip version to be linked with current python instalation

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks promising but I want to get rid of the python installations I am not using before I proceed to install pyenv. How do I know which of these pyhton installations I can remove?

Comment: After following all the instruction I have the following error:
`Stevens-MacBook-Pro:~ setegonz$ python ––version`
`/Users/setegonz/.pyenv/versions/3.8.1/bin/python: can't open file '––version': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`
`Stevens-MacBook-Pro:~ setegonz$ python –version`